# Multiple inputs in Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I want to change values of two my inputs in Redux, but for some reasons it does not work.

```
// My code in component
 <Input label="name" value={initialUser.name} onChange={(e) => dispatch(onChangeInputAction(e))} name="name" />
 <Input label="username" value={initialUser.userName} onChange={(e) => dispatch(onChangeInputAction(e))} name="userName" />
```

```
// code from redux

const initialUser: IInitialUser = {
  name: '',
  userName: '',
  id: null,
};

 case CustomersActionsEnum.ONCHANGE_INPUT:
      const {value, name} = action.payload.currentTarget;

      return {...state, initialUser: {...initialUser, [name]: value}};

//action creator

export const onChangeInputAction = (payload:React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => ({type: CustomersActionsEnum.ONCHANGE_INPUT, payload});
```

I read that the best idea is to use name from input as a key, I follow this piece of advise, but it does not work.

The problem when I write something in one input, everything is ok, but when I start to write in another input, first input gets clear and the value appears only in the second input.

Comment: Can you share a more complete [mcve] such that we can see initial state value this case is trying to update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are overwriting `state.initialUser` with `const initialUser`.

You probably meant to spread `...state.initialUser`

```js
const initialUser: IInitialUser = {
  name: '',
  userName: '',
  id: null,
};

 case CustomersActionsEnum.ONCHANGE_INPUT:
      const {value, name} = action.payload.currentTarget;

      return {...state, initialUser: {...state.initialUser, [name]: value}};
```